# Remove rows that are the same as rows from another CSV

Tags: python, numpy, rows

I'm trying to loop through each row of 2 CSV files. If there are lat and lon fields that are the same in both files I would like to discard this row.

I've tried the following

```
import numpy
f=numpy.genfromtxt('/wind/addandclaimwithinlatlon.csv', delimiter=',', 
                   dtype=None, skiprows=0)
f1=numpy.genfromtxt('/wind/new_2011.csv',delimiter=",",dtype=None,skiprows=0)
final=[]
for row in f:
    for row1 in f1:
        if row[1]==row1[0] and row[2]==row1[1]:
            print "duplicates"
        else:
            final.append([row[0],row[1],row[2]])

numpy.savetxt('/wind/addclaimwithinlatlonwithout2011.csv',
               final, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
```

It does not fail, but it just runs for a very long time and does not produce any output. What is the issue with it? Is there any other way to do this faster?

Comment: Does the `numpy.genfromtxt` method loads the text correctly?

Comment: it does not print anything. right now still running

Comment: I would print not only the duplicates but every line to see what's happening and in order to see what is the format numpy.genfromtxt reads the data.

Comment: You can put a print after `f1=numpy.genfromtxt ...` and see that it print any thing or not?

Comment: it is loaded successfullly both file

Answer (score 1):

Since your files have been loaded successfully, it seems that the problem is with your code.

So instead of multiple indexing and a nested loop you can use `itertools.zip_longest` (in python 2.X `izip_longest`) to zip your files then use a list comprehension to preserve the expected rows.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import numpy
f=numpy.genfromtxt('/wind/addandclaimwithinlatlon.csv',delimiter=",",dtype=None,skiprows=0)
f1=numpy.genfromtxt('/wind/new_2011.csv',delimiter=",",dtype=None,skiprows=0)
final=[row for row,row1 in zip_longest(f,f1) if len(row)>3 and len(row1)>1 and row[1:3]!=row1[:2]]
```

Note that instead of multiple indexing for comparing `row[1],row[2]` with `row1[0],row[1]` you can use one slicing.

Comment: if should be if row[1:3]!=row1[:2]??

Comment: since i want the ones that is not equal to the one that is already existed.

Comment: it said cannot import zip_longest

Comment: @alice As I said if you are using python 2 you need to use `izip_longest`.

Comment: @alice That's because of that length of some rows are not 4 or ... . for get ride of that you can check the length of rows too.

Comment: the script is correct, but the output file is 0 byte. i tried to print it out the two input file f[1:5], f1[1:5], it gives me the following [('"yes"', 38.2983, -77.95571) ('"yes"', 38.89956, -99.337907)
 ('"yes"', 35.6224, -97.467335) ('"yes"', 33.324906, -111.828779)]
[[ 34.66721  -99.22994 ]
 [ 34.661566 -99.342412]
 [ 35.50248  -97.559962]
 [ 35.201083 -97.195707]]

Comment: one is a tuple array, another is list array. is that the reason why the output file is empty. and the index error. because the two files should have no empty rows and the columns are all uniformed

Answer (score 0):

import numpy
from itertools import izip_longest
f=numpy.genfromtxt('/wind/addandclaimwithinlatlon.csv',delimiter=",",dtype=None,skiprows=0)
f1=numpy.genfromtxt('/wind/new_2011.csv',delimiter=",",dtype=None,skiprows=0)
final=[]
for row,row1 in izip_longest(f,f1):
    row2=list(row)
    #lat=row2[1]
    #lon=row2[2]
    if row2[1:3].all()==row1[:2].all():
        print "dup"
    else:
        final.append(row)

numpy.savetxt('/wind/addclaimwithinlatlonwithout2011.csv',final,delimiter=",",fmt='%s')

it is still now working. error. List object has no attribute 'all'
even if i assign each column as different variable, it said nontype object is not subscriptable